# Allowing users to SSH into EC2 Linux Instance with key pairs

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, putty

I created a new EC2 Amazon Linux instance.  I want to allow a developer to SSH into the EC2 instance.  To test this, I'm trying it from my windows computer.  I have followed the instructions in the link below but I can't get SSH (Putty) to connect using the key pair I'm generating.

I'm following the instructions here as [reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html)
and [here](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1233/)

After logging into EC2 as ec2-user using FireSSH and the pem generated by AWS, I use SSH to run the following commands to create a new user, .ssh directory, and permissions.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo adduser newuser

[ec2-user ~]$ sudo su - newuser

[newuser ~]$ mkdir .ssh

[newuser ~]$ touch .ssh/authorized_keys

[newuser ~]$ chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys

[newuser ~]$ vim .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then I paste a public key into `authorized_keys` using `vim`.  I will explain where I get the public key in the next step.

```
ssh-rsaAAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQClKsfkNkuS ....
```

To create the public key which I pasted in the previous step I followed the steps in this reference starting at ["Generating an SSH Key"](http://wiki.joyent.com/wiki/display/jpc2/Manually+Generating+Your+SSH+Key+in+Windows)

I copied the public key from PuttyKeyGen which is showed in the box labeled "Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys".  Then I pasted that into the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on my EC2 instance in the `newuser` directory.

I log out of the SSH client on EC2.  Then I try to login with Putty using the newly created private key on my windows machine.  I use the `newuser` login name.  I get this error in Putty:  `server refused our key`.  There is also a dialog box that says `Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available {server sent: publickey)`

What am I doing wrong in these steps?

Answer (score 1):

I did two things different and it works now.  It's probably the number of bits that made it work.

I generated a new key pair using PuttyGen but I specified `SSH-2 RSA` with `1024` bits instead of the default that PuttyGen was putting in which was like `2048`.

When I logged back into EC2 with my SSH I pasted the public key using nano instead of vim.

Answer (score 0):

Always use ec2-import-keypair features to verified whether it is GOOD for EC2 instance. It the import works, then it is good, otherwise, regen a compliance keypair.   If you simply copy a keypair that is not compliance , you will run into trouble.

Here is the document for [import key pair](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-ImportKeyPair.html)

> - OpenSSH public key format (the format in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys)
> - Base64 encoded DER format SSH public key file format as specified in
> - RFC4716 DSA keys **are not supported**. Make sure your key generator is
>     set up to create RSA keys.
> - Supported lengths: **1024, 2048, and 4096**.